# How to trigger click event for datalist in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, events, click, html-datalist

I am trying to trigger a click event on a datalist input field when clicked on another element in angular 9 but nothing seems to be working.

I've tried native element, renderer2, dispatchEvent and nothing seems to be triggering the click event.

here is the stack blitz example with sample code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/datalist-dummy-test

and here is the example code

```html
<input
  #myDiv
  type="text"
  id="test"
  list="codes"
  [(ngModel)]="codeValue"
  (change)="saveCode($event)"
/>
<datalist id="codes">
  <option *ngFor="let c of codeList" [value]="c.name">{{c.name}}</option>
</datalist>
<span (click)="testfn()"> test<span></span></span>
```

```js
  public codeValue: string;

  codeList = [
    { id: 1, name: "Angular 2+" },
    { id: 2, name: "Angular 4" },
    { id: 3, name: "Angular 5" },
    { id: 4, name: "Angular 6" },
    { id: 5, name: "Angular 7" }
  ];

  @ViewChild("myDiv") myDiv: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  constructor(private ref: ElementRef) {}

  public saveCode(e): void {
    let name = e.target.value;
    let list = this.codeList.filter(x => x.name === name)[0];
    console.log(list.id);
  }

  testfn() {
    debugger;
    console.log("test");
    let dummy = this.ref.nativeElement.querySelector("#test");
    dummy.click();
    dummy.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
    let el: HTMLElement = this.myDiv.nativeElement;
    el.click();
  }
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly - instead of `dummy.click();` do `dummy.focus();`

Answer (score 0):

Click event on an input is `focus`.
So try to replace `dummy.click();` with `dummy.focus();`.
I hope it answered your question.

Comment: I've tried dummy.focus(). It's focussing the input field but not showing the options.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand that you wanted to show `datalist` tag in unusual way. I don't think it is possible.